# Basic authentication script only works the first time

Tags: rest, powershell, curl

I am working a bit on a powershell script I have that can modify files and folders on a url through REST calls, so using Invoke-RestMethod, but I guess this applies for any invoke webrequests or in general trying to make it work as an equivalent of how curl "username:password@host:port/path" would work in linux.

My issue is that I need to pass credentials like I would in curl. It works fine doing my first call when I pass the credentials using -Credential 
The problem is when I want to perform further operations in the script or use it a second time right after, then I am no longer being prompted and so my script just hangs.

The relevant part of the code:

```
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypass" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("myuser",$securepassword)
$URI = "http://myhost:myport/mypath/"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Credential $credentials -Method DELETE
```

This works totally fine the first time it is run, but second time it will hang and I am guessing it is because the credential prompt doesn't come because it is stored for a while. However I can make several calls using curl right after each other with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you need to pass some sort of authorization item in subsequent requests. In the few REST applications I have built it usually goes like this:

1. Send request with credentials.
2. Receive response indicating authentication/log-in was successful. The response should include some item (a key?) that you append to subsequent requests.
3. Include authorization token in subsequent requests. The most recent REST app I built uses a `userID` to obtain an API key, and then in subsequent requests it sends a key/val pair in the header `'x-api-key' => 'theActualKeyValue'`. Perhaps you can do something similar.